# Is there any way to automate Pacing for multiple scripts in Loadrunner or Performance Center?

Tags: vbscript, loadrunner

Problem statement : Our project require to execute multiple scripts( ~ 200) at a time and need to modify pacing (~ 10% increase in previous pacing value) for each script for every execution . Is there any way we can automate Runtime settings for pacing, which lessen the efforts of script maintenance time before execution? (HP Performance Center is used for execution).

We have identified the file i.e. default.usp, which contains Runtime settings and is unique for each script. Not sure about automating the file because scripts are saved at ALM cloud repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use sleep() statements embedded within your script to adjust think times and pacing.   For instance, you could take a seed value, say 10000, and divide that by the iteration pacing to have a decaying delay per iteration

```
 Action()
 {
       /*My Code*/
       sleep(10000/atoi( lr_eval_string( "{my_iteration_param}" ) ) );
       return 0;
 }
```

Set your iteration pacing in your run time settings to iterate immediately or use "return 1;" to iterate immediately and ignore the runtime settings.

The sleep statement will not be affected by your think time settings.

Comment: James much appreciate your reply but this seems to be helpful for multiple iteration within the script and sleep() is not recommended : https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60-12.62/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/scripting/lrFr_script_sleep.html scripts does not respond to Stop or Pause commands when sleep is called. I have set of 200 scripts with different pacing per script; for every next set of run I need to change the pacing of each script by ~10%.

Comment: If you want to change it on the fly, then sleep() is your only option.   If you are going to change it between iterations, then I recommend you look to your .lrs file, or loadrunner scenario file.   This is a text file, despite the extension.  You can find the run time settings in the file.  You would need to write some code to adjust the values in the run time settings and then re-save the file.